# Dura Ace 9100 chainring on Ultegra 8000 crank?

Tags: chainring

I mounted a Dura Ace 55T 9100 on a Ultegra 8000 crank. It fit fine but on two sides on the ”outside” the crank and the chain ring is slightly misaligned. The shapes do not fully match. I just wanted to double check that it is as it should?

[image]

Comment: The shapes are meant not to match. That's the way Shimano uses to keep you from mixing hardware-

Answer (score 5):

The shaped ‘arms’ of Dura Ace 9000 and Ultegra 8000 series cranks that continue from the crank body into the chainrings have different profiles, so the ring from one is not going to match either the crank body of the other.

If you don’t care about the asthetics it’s not a problem.